# The application is not installed on iphone because it is not signed

Tags: iphone, signed

When I try to install my app. to client's iphone I got this type of error:The application is not installed on iphone because it is not signed.

Answer (score 1):

Just try to change build target from Simulator to Device, it did helped me.

Comment: Yes @NR4TR.  I had all my build settings-->code signing correct.  I had thought--because I was doing a "Build", rather than a "Build and Run" or a "Build and Debug", that it didn't matter if the target was Simulator or Device.  Well, it does matter.  Now we know.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are a member of the enterprise development programme and deploying to 'in-house' devices then to download an app to a device you either need to..

1 - Submit it to App Store with a release profile and then download from there

or (and this sounds like what you are trying to to)

2 - Create either a development profile or ad-hoc distribution profile for the client's device, and download that to their phone, then try to download the app.

To create the profile for the client device you will of course need the UDID for the device which you will be able to find in the organizer or iTunes

See [this page](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/manage/devices/howto.action) in the developer portal for details on assigning devices for provisioning

Answer (score 0):

Set the target to Signing Savvy | iOS Device

Then in Xcode From the product menu=>Build For=> Build For Testing